# Redirecting to xml with query string in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, xml, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml, iis-8

I am doing a Response.Redirect to below given xml document with a query string parameter.

```
 Response.Redirect(@"../temp/output.xml?location=newlocation");
```

What I want is that the value of location attribute for all the product nodes should be replaced with the value I pass in query string parameter. The problem is when I do a response.redirect to xml the c# server code which modifies the xml document does not executes for the obvious reason that xml file does not runs any server code.

Can anyone please suggest a solution for this.

**Xml File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<products xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="products:noNamespaceSchemaLocation">
<store id="BND088412">
  <display-name>test</display-name>
</store>
  <product location="test">
     <length units="minutes">100</length>
     <title>Microsoft Excel</title>
  </product>
  <product location="test">
     <length units="minutes">300</length>
     <title>Microsoft VBA</title>
  </product>
</products>
```

***Thanks & Regards***

Comment: You have to redirect to web page that would do the processing you need and write the xml. Redirecting to a static file won't work - the static file won't modify itself regardless of how many parameters you will include - the server will just serve the file and the parameters will be ignored.